# OpenGL Index Buffering To Make A Square

Tags: c++, opengl, indexing, buffer

I'm new to OpenGL and have been following the YouTube tutorial by Jeffrey Chastine. As a personal exercise, I wanted to make a simple square using index buffers. Sadly with my attempt, I only see one triangle drawn (when I expect two). I'm not sure what I'm missing. Here is my code, I tried explaining my logic/reasoning in the comments. Feel free to correct me wherever I'm wrong:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>

#define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ((char *)NULL + (i))
GLuint shaderProgramID;
GLuint vao = 0;
GLuint vbo;
GLuint positionID, colorID;
GLuint indexBufferID;


#pragma region SHADER_FUNCTIONS

static char* readFile(const char* fileName)
{
    //Open the file
    FILE* fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

    //Move the file pointer to the end of the file and determining the length
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long file_length = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* contents = new char[file_length + 1];

    //zero out memory
    for(int i = 0; i < file_length+1; i++)
    {
        contents[i] = 0;
    }

    //Here's the actual read
    fread(contents, 1, file_length, fp);
    contents[file_length + 1] = '\0';
    fclose(fp);
    return contents;
}

bool compiledStatus(GLint shaderID){
    GLint compiled = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
    if (compiled) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        GLint logLength;
        glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
        char* msgBuffer = new char[logLength];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, logLength, NULL, msgBuffer);
        printf ("%s\n", msgBuffer);
        delete (msgBuffer);
        return false;
    }
}

//Takes in source code as string
GLuint makeVertexShader(const char* shaderSource)
{
    //Call GL to make a vertex shader and get the ID
    GLuint vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    //Bind the provided source code to the shader ID
    glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, 1, (const GLchar**)&shaderSource, NULL);

    //Compile the vertex Shader
    glCompileShader(vertexShaderID);

    bool compiledCorrect = compiledStatus(vertexShaderID);
    if(compiledCorrect)
    {
        return vertexShaderID;
    }
    return -1;

    return vertexShaderID;
}

GLuint makeFragmentShader(const char* shaderSource)
{
    //Call GL to make a fragment shader and get the ID
    GLuint fragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    //Bind the provided source code to the shader ID
    glShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, 1, (const GLchar**)&shaderSource, NULL);
    //Compile the fragment Shader
    glCompileShader(fragmentShaderID);

    bool compiledCorrect = compiledStatus(fragmentShaderID);
    if(compiledCorrect)
    {
        return fragmentShaderID;
    }
    return -1;

    return fragmentShaderID;
}

#pragma endregion SHADER_FUNCTIONS 

void changeViewport(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

//This is the function we are using each time the window needs to be redrawn
void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

GLuint makeShaderProgram(GLuint vertextShaderID, GLuint fragmentShaderID)
{
    GLuint shaderID = glCreateProgram();
    //Attach the vertex shader to the shader program
    glAttachShader(shaderID, vertextShaderID);

    //Attatch the fragment shader to the shader program
    glAttachShader(shaderID, fragmentShaderID);

    //Link all the shaders together
    glLinkProgram(shaderID);
    return shaderID;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Standards
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Test");
    glutReshapeFunc(changeViewport);
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glewInit();

    //Verticies
    GLfloat vertices_0[] = {-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, //0 -> Bottom Left
                            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, //1 -> Top Left
                             0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, //2 -> Bottom Right
                             0.05f, 0.5f, 0.0f};//3 -> Top Right
    //Colors
    GLfloat colors_0[] = {1.0f, 0.0, 0.0f, 1.0f,//0
                          0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,//1
                          0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,//2
                          1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};//3

    //Indicies -> Triangle 1 -> 0 1 2, Traingle 2 -> 1 3 2
    GLuint indicies_0[] = {0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2};


    //Read the vertex shader
    char* vertexShaderSourceCode = readFile("vertexShader.vsh");

    //Read the fragment shader
    char* fragmentShaderSourceCode = readFile("fragmentShader.fsh");

    //Make Vertex Shader
    GLuint vertexShaderID = makeVertexShader(vertexShaderSourceCode);

    //Make Fragment Shader
    GLuint fragmentShaderID = makeFragmentShader(fragmentShaderSourceCode);

    //Make Shader Program
    shaderProgramID = makeShaderProgram(vertexShaderID, fragmentShaderID);


    printf("Vertex Shader ID is %d\n", vertexShaderID);
    printf("Fragment Shader ID is %d\n", fragmentShaderID);
    printf("Shader Program ID is %d\n", shaderProgramID);
    printf("s_vPosition's ID is %d\n", positionID);

    //Create vertex array object
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);

    //Bind Vertex array object
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    //Create vertex buffer object
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

    //Bind vertex buffer object
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

    //Create Buffer ->7 Values for 4 vertices
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 7*4*sizeof(GLfloat), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //Starting at the beggining of the buffer, place the position data (3 values for 4 verticies)
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 3*4*sizeof(GLfloat), vertices_0);

    //Starting after the placement of position data, place the color data (4 values for 4 verticies)
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3*4*sizeof(GLfloat), 4*4*sizeof(GLfloat), colors_0);

    //Generate the index buffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBufferID);

    //Bind the buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferID);

    //Place index buffer data for the 6 indicies
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6*sizeof(GLuint), indicies_0, GL_STATIC_DRAW); 

    //Get the position attribute from the shader
    positionID = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, "s_vPosition");

    //Get the color attribute from the shader
    colorID = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, "s_vColor");

    //Tell the variables where they can find its info in the buffer
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionID, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(colorID, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(vertices_0)));

    //Tell the program to use the shader program
    glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);
    //Turn on the position variable in the shader
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionID);
    //Turn on the color variable in the shader
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorID);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It certainly wouldn't be a square because one of the coordinates is `0.05f` instead of `0.5f`. But it shouldn't be a triangle either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there is an error in your vertices definition (0.05f should be 0.5f).

But, the reason you are only seeing one triangle instead of 2 is this line:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
```

The second parameter is described in the [OpenGL documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawElements.xhtml) as

> count - Specifies the number of elements to be rendered.

which is the index count (each element is referenced by an entry in your index array), and so should be the number of entries in your index array, not the number of unique indexes. So change the 4 to a 6.

Note that if you used `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` or `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` instead of `GL_TRIANGLES` you would only need 4 indexes {0, 1, 2, 3} and you could pass 4 as you are doing, because each triangle after the first one shares 2 of its indexes with the previous triangle, for a total index count of (triangle count + 2). However when using `GL_TRIANGLES`, each triangle is specified separately with 3 indexes for each (triangle count * 3).